# Retrieve youtube channel information using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, youtube-channels

I want to build a rails 4 app that I can basically search for a channel by either the channel_name or if I enter a random link it will retrieve the channel_id and some other data.

What I have done so far is not get anything like that working but I am able to retrieve a youtube video by searching the url and pull in the video and data from it.

I am using the Youtube_it api and I am just wondering if anybody out there can shed some light on how to search or retrieve information about the channel.

The regular expression I am using to work with the videos will not work with the channel and I am unable to find any relevant information about how I would approach this problem.